# Strange behaviour of list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

I'm learning basics of Haskell and trying to solve project Euler's simple tasks: find largest palindrome of 3 digit numbers (100.999). I wrote this code:

```
palindrome = maximum $ filter (\a -> reverse a == a) $
                                    map show [ x*y :: Int | x <- [100 .. 999],
                                                            y <- [x, x+1 .. 999]]
```

It gives a wrong answer = 99999, when I change it to `x <- [307 .. 999]`answer still is wrong: 94249 (all palindromes, but not the largest) and finally when I change it to `x <- [308 .. 999],` it gives me right answer: 906609.

I really don't understand this behaviour: it seems there is some kind of overflow and truncation happens inside the generated list. Can someone explain me this wrong behaviour? I **don't want** you to answer the task: i know my solution is not very efficient. I just want you to explain this code behaviour (list truncation or memory issues). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of `filter` is a list of `String` values, so `maximum` is comparing them lexicographically. You need to convert the values back to `Int`s  first. The type signature ensures that `read` returns values of the correct type.

```
palindrome :: Int
palindrome = maximum . map read . filter ...
```

Another approach is to only convert a value to a `String` in the filter itself:

```
palindrome :: Int
palindrome = maximum $ filter (\a -> let sa = show a in reverse sa == sa) [ x*y | x <- [100..999], y <- [x..999]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but lexicographical order is alphabetical order preceded by a length comparison, so 906609 is still larger than 99999. Why comparison result changes only when I change the bound?

Comment: Length is checked *after* alphabetical order. `"aaaaaaaaaa" < "b"`.

Comment: By changing the lower bound on `x`, you are eliminating the numbers that consist of all 9s.